# Unable to format dates to put in event calendar

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development

What i want to achieve is to get dates through get_post_meta and push them in array and passing it into js code. But when i use below code first post in loop's dates gets formatted and other posts dates showing 01-01-1970. Working since 5 hours any help will be appreciated.

Here is wordpress the code.

```
 <?php 

function bpem_event_calendar_tab() {

global $bp;



if (isset($bp->groups->current_group->slug)) {

bp_core_new_subnav_item(array(

'name' => 'Event Calendar',

'slug' => 'events-calendar',

'parent_slug' => $bp->groups->current_group->slug,

'parent_url' => bp_get_group_permalink($bp->groups->current_group),

'screen_function' => 'bpem_event_calendar_roup_show_screen',

'position' => 90));

}

}



add_action('wp', 'bpem_event_calendar_tab');



function bpem_event_calendar_roup_show_screen() {



//add_action('bp_template_title', 'ev_new_group_show_screen_title');

add_action('bp_template_content', 'bpem_event_calendar_group_show_screen_content');



$templates = array('groups/single/plugins.php', 'plugin-template.php');

if (strstr(locate_template($templates), 'groups/single/plugins.php')) {

bp_core_load_template(apply_filters('bp_core_template_plugin', 'groups/single/plugins'));

} else {

bp_core_load_template(apply_filters('bp_core_template_plugin', 'plugin-template'));

}

}



/*function ev_new_group_show_screen_title() {

echo 'New Tab Title';

}*/



function bpem_event_calendar_group_show_screen_content() {
$group_name =  sanitize_title(bp_get_current_group_name());
$event_data = array();

$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'bpem_event',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
/*   'meta_key'          => 'evn_group_slug',
'meta_value'     => $group_name,*/

);
$i=0;
$event_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $event_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $event_query->have_posts() ) :       
$event_query->the_post();

$start_date = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'evn_startDate');
//print_r($start_date);
$start_d = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date[$i]));
//echo $start_d.'<br>';

$start_time =   get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'evn_startTime');
$start_t    =   date("H:i:s", strtotime($start_time[$i]));


$end_date = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'evn_endDate');
//print_r($end_date);
$end_d = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($end_date[$i]));
//echo $end_d;

$end_time = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'evn_endTime');
$end_t = date("H:i:s", strtotime($end_time[$i]));


$event_data[] = array(
'title'         =>  get_the_title(),
'start'         =>  $start_d.'T'.$start_t,
'end'           =>  $end_d.'T'.$end_t
//'end_date'        => $enddate[0]
);
$i++;
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
endif;
$json = json_encode($event_data);
print_r($json);

echo "<div id='bpem-calendar'></div>";

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var todayDate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date());
jQuery('#bpem-calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
left: 'prev,next today',
center: 'title',
right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
defaultDate: todayDate,
businessHours: true, // display business hours
editable: false,
events:<?php echo json_encode($event_data); ?>
});

});

</script>

<?php 

} ?>
```

This is the output.

> [{"title":"JSON Expert
>   Meetup","start":"2019-03-25T07:00:00","end":"2019-03-27T09:30:00"},{"title":"WordPress
>   MeetUp
>   Karachi","start":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","end":"1970-01-01T00:00:00"},{"title":"WP
>   Meetup
>   Karachi","start":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","end":"1970-01-01T00:00:00"},{"title":"JQuery
>   Masters
>   Meetup","start":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","end":"1970-01-01T00:00:00"}]

Comment: I don't think you want `$start_date[$i]`. You probably are looking for `$start_date[0]`. I would check out what `$start_date` looks like.

Comment: Bundle of thanks mike problem solved and yes that was the issue thumbs up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want `$start_date[$i]`. You probably are looking for `$start_date[0]`. That's why you're only getting the first result and none of the following results. `1970-01-01T00:00:00` is the epoch time and shows up because `strtotime()` cannot convert the date you're giving it, so that's what it returns by default.

I would check out what `$start_date` looks like.